# Подскажите простейшую хэш-функцию, реализуемую в VkScript?

Tags: алгоритм, vkontakte-api, вконтакте, хеширование, vkscript

[VKScript](https://dev.vk.com/method/execute) – это JavaScript-подобный язык, совершенно урезанный, поддерживающий лишь несколько конструкций и операторов. Он выполняется на стороне ВКонтакте, и его код можно хранить в настройках приложения, делая его скрытым от пользователей.

Мне нужно защитить от подделок некий параметр, передаваемый с моего сервера, в браузер посетителей, и оттуда – в вызов методов ВК api.

План простой: на сервере считать хэш от этого параметра, секрета и id пользователя, который нельзя подделать при обращении к api ВКонтакте. А в коде процедуры `execute` проверять эту подпись. Всё бы хорошо, но в VKScript нет функции `md5(...)` и, наверное, не реализовать из-за ограничений языка, числа повторов в циклах и т.п.

**Подскажите хэш-функцию.** Пусть, не достаточно безопасную для банков, но и не примитивно взламываемую школьниками, которую можно реализовать в рамках VKScript.

---

VKScript поддерживает только вот такие вещи:

- Арифметические операции.
- Логические операции: `<` (меньше), `>` (больше), `<=` (меньше или равно), `>=` (больше или равно), `==` (равно) и `!=` (не равно). В данный момент поддерживаются сравнения:

  - Двух строк.
  - Двух чисел.
  - Строки и числа. Строка приводится к числу.

  Результат логического выражения может быть использован в управляющей конструкции `if...[[else...]]`.
- Создание массивов и списков (`[X,Y]`).
- `parseInt` и `parseDouble`.
- Объединение строк (`+`).
- Условный оператор (`if`).
- Выборка массива по параметру (`@.`).
- Вызовы методов API, параметр `length`.
- Циклы с использованием оператора `while`.
- Методы Javascript:

  - Работа с массивами: `slice`, `push`, `pop`, `shift`, `unshift`, `splice`.
  - Работа со строками: `substr`, `split`.
- Оператор `delete`.
- Присваивания элементам маcсива, например: `row.user.action = "test"`.
- Поиск в массиве или строке — `indexOf`. Возвращается `-1`, если элемент не найден. Пример: `"123".indexOf(2) = 1, [[1, 2, 3]].indexOf(3) = 2`.

Из битовых операций поддерживаются только `&`, `|`, `~`, `<<` и `>>`. А вот XOR'а `^`, который бы очень помог, нет. Также ограничено [количество операций](https://habr.com/ru/post/464099/) – сложные алгоритмы не реализовать.

Upd. XOR, как мне [подсказали](https://toster.ru/q/298152#comment_1017757), реализуется: `a xor b == (a|b)&~(a&b)`, так же, как и сдвиг с заполнением: `a >>> b == (a >> b) & (a<<(32 - b))`, при условии b < 32.

Comment: И 32 бита я так подозреваю маловато, хеш Дженкинса не подойдет ...

Comment: 32 бита вполне. Главное, чтобы не тривиально было самостоятельно генерировать валидные подписи любителям программирования.

Comment: Битовый сдвиг есть ? в принципе на делением/умножением на степени двойки можно заменить https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A5%D0%B5%D1%88-%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D0%94%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%81%D0%B0

Comment: ещё одна засада – нет метода `charCodeAt()` – как ещё получить ASCII-код символа?

Comment: Если набор символов ограничен, то создать массив `a['A']=1 ....` Ели есть String.fromCharCode то заполнить массив циклом на его основе

Comment: Хор делается через энд, ор, нот.  `Х^У=(неХ и У) или (X и неУ)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Собственно, всё решилось [хешем Дженкинса](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A5%D0%B5%D1%88-%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D0%94%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%81%D0%B0) примерно в такой реализации. Код хранимой процедуры ВК:

```js
var secret = 123456,
    uid = API.users.get()[0].id,
    param = parseInt(Args.param),
    signature = parseInt(Args.signature),
    toCrypt = [param, uid, secret],
    b,
    hash = 0;
    
while (toCrypt.length) {
    hash = hash + toCrypt.pop();
    hash = hash + (hash << 10);
    b = hash >> 6;
    hash = (hash|b)&~(hash&b);
}

hash = hash + (hash << 3);
b = hash >> 11;
hash = (hash|b)&~(hash&b);
hash = hash + (hash << 15);
    
if (hash != signature) return {"error": "bad signature"};
    
return {"result": "some $$$ data"};
```

С сервера в клиент передаётся параметр и подпись, вычисляемая как 32-битный хеш от важного параметра, id пользователя (он логинится на сайт через ВК), и секрета (32-битное число). В хранимой процедуре можно проверить, что параметр не подделан.

Например, параметром может быть `timestamp`, до которого у юзера оплачена платная подписка. Получить текущее время на стороне ВК можно методом `API.utils.getServertime()`.

Answer (score 0):

Я не знаю, почему метод до сих пор не опубликован, но внутри хранимых процедур можно использовать `apps.getSecretHash` с параметрами `app_id` и `request_id` (строка, которую нужно подписать).

Пример:

```
var hash = API.apps.getSecretHash({
  app_id: 0,
  request_id: "string for hash",
});
```

Answer (score -1):

A xor B = (A and !B) or (!A and B)

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение?

Comment: Дискретная математика)

Comment: Дизюктивная нормальна форма